# express-session: NPM dependency not listed in documentation?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, express-session

Following [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local), I have installed express-session using this code:

```
 npm install express-session --save --save-exact
```

But now when I try to run the code, node is telling me I need a package called "buffer-crc32"

I see this listed as a require() in the drive where I install express-session, but I'm confused because the index.js file stored on my computer seems different from the one shown on github [here](https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/master/index.js).

What gives? Why isn't that dependency installing when I run "npm install" or "npm update"? Thanks.

Comment: I get this from time to time, seems to be an issue with `npm` missing some dependencies. Usually solved by removing `node_modules/` and running `npm install` (or, possibly, `npm install --force`)

Comment: try running the `npm install`  again . I hope that will resolve the issue.

Comment: I tried both comments and neither one worked :(

Comment: I figured it out. I had to stop using '--save-exact' in my npm install command and update the version in my package.json document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to stop using '--save-exact' in my npm install command and update the version in my package.json document